# Oneliner to prepend or append a string to another

Tags: php, string

Not a vital question, just wondering if there is any onliner to do this.

```
function addString($text, $add, $type = 'prepend') {
   // oneliner here
   return $text;
}

$text = 'World';
addString($text, 'Hello ', 'prepend'); // returns 'Hello World'
addString($text, ' Hello', 'append'); // returns 'World Hello'
```

Any ideas? : )

Comment: Irrespective of my answer, I'd have to say that creating a function for this is probably un-necessary unless you're likely to be carrying out such operations in circumstances where you don't know if you need to prepend/append. (i.e.: Don't use this in place of `$text .= $add`, etc.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about this, using the [ternary `?:` operator](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.php) :

```
function addString($text, $add, $type = 'prepend') {
   return $type=='prepend' ? $add . $text : $text . $add;
}
```

*Note : I actually would probably not use that -- and stay with a classic if/else : not a one-liner, not as nice to read... But probably a lot easier to understand ; and having understandable code is what trully matters.*

Edit after the comment : if you want to make sure that the `$type` is either `'append'` or `'prepend'`, and still want a one-liner, you could go with something like this :

```
function addString($text, $add, $type = 'prepend') {
   return ($type=='prepend' ? $add . $text : ($type=='append' ? $text . $add : ''));
}
```

But your code will become harder to read -- and it's probably time to go with something that's longer than just one line of code, and easier to understand.

For example, why not something like this :

```
function addString($text, $add, $type = 'prepend') {
    if ($type === 'prepend') {
        return $add . $text;
    } else if ($type === 'append') {
        return $text . $add;
    } else {
        // Do some kind of error-handling
        // like throwing an exception, for instance
    }
}
```

After all, the number of lines has pretty much no impact on the way the code is executed -- and, again, what matters is that your code is easy to understand and maintain.

Comment: I thought about the Ternary operator, but I want to be sure that's 'prepend' or 'append', what if someone provide something else?!

Comment: Have to agree with your point on code legibility, but I think a single ternary operator is pretty much OK in this day and age. (When people start nesting them, it's time for a bit of a chat though.) :-)

Comment: @JohnT I've edited my answer with a couple more notes ;; @middaparka true about one ternary operator, but, as you say, nesting them leads to hell... and I've seen those nested so often...

Comment: Ok, thank you, I agree with all your comments, it is actually just about curiosity : )

Comment: Ok :-) Curiosity is more than fine : that's how people learn ;-) Have fun, so !

Answer (score 1):

Are you familiar with the . in PHP?

For example:

```
echo $text . "Hello!";
```

http://www.phpf1.com/tutorial/php-string-concatenation.html

Answer (score 0):

```
return $type == 'prepend' ? $add . $text : $text . $add;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) to achieve this as follows:

```
function addString($text, $add, $type = 'prepend') {
   return $type == 'prepend' ? $add . $text : $text . $add;
}
```

What the ternary operator is effectively doing is checking the first condition (the one prior to the `?` to see if it evaluates to true. If it does, it sets the return value of the statement to `$add . $text`, if not if uses the final block (after the `:`) to set the return value to `$text . $add`.

As the PHP manual puts it:

> The expression (expr1) ? (expr2) :
>   (expr3) evaluates to expr2 if expr1
>   evaluates to TRUE, and expr3 if expr1
>   evaluates to FALSE.

As such, if someone provides something other than '`prepend`' as the `$type` argument's value, then this will always default to the second condition and append.

Answer (score 0):

$text = ($type === 'prepend') ? $add.$text : $text.$add;